# How to keep signed in on IOS with FirebaseAuth

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using phone number login method with firebaseAuth, It works fine on Android but it keeps log out every time build and run a code on IOS.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement( new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()));
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement( new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }
```

The user is always null on IOS, Is there any specific setting needed to keep signed in on IOS?

Answer (score 0):

As per Firestore Flutter documentation there is nothing you need to do to set up persistence across loads, it is done for you.
See https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#persisting-authentication-state

It helps to create the listener right after you have initialized the firebase instance

```
Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
  // Start listening to auth changes
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
    // If user ever becomes null then log out
    if (user == null) {
      // Handle logout
    }
  });
```

Another tip is that anytime AFTER you have initialized your firebase app you can check whether or not a user is currently logged in by checking

`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`

So what you can try is instead of using the authStateChanges listener (which is really just meant for handling changes, ) you can just check whether or not a user is currently signed in or not before you navigate to the next screen. A splash page can be used while you wait for the future of initializing firebase to complete.